# Vuetify setting right to left text

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I added **`Vuetify`** using:

```
vue add vuetify
```

the resulting file looks like this:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import vuetify from "./plugins/vuetify";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  vuetify,
  render: (h) => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

I tried adding **RTL** doing the fallowing:

```
import vuetify from "./plugins/vuetify";

const Vuetify = new vuetify({
  rtl: true
});;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  Vuetify, 
  render: (h) => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

Got an error: `Uncaught TypeError: _plugins_vuetify__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__.default is not a constructor`

And tried this:

```
Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  rtl: true
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  render: (h) => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

Got error:  `Error in beforeCreate hook: "Error: Vuetify is not properly initialized,`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not changing it in the right place. Looks like you're trying to modify the file `main.js`, you should modify the file at `src/plugins/vuetify.js` instead. Also make sure to do it under the `export default` like described in the [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/rtl/).

Like this:

```
// src/plugins/vuetify.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify({
  rtl: true,
})
```